# How can i pass kinect tracking into another form

Tags: wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have a kinect project in wpf and it uses skeleton stream that tracks the left and right hand of its users and allows me to hover over buttons.

I tried making a new form and just copying and pasting everything so i can create a new page but it didnt work, i think i may have to reference the methods used in the main page, but i am unsure.

I want to be able to use the skeleton stream alongside the hovering method in a new window

Any help would be appreciated - i apologize if this does not make sense i am a beginner

Code

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private KinectSensor _Kinect;
        private WriteableBitmap _ColorImageBitmap;
        private Int32Rect _ColorImageBitmapRect;
        private int _ColorImageStride;
        private Skeleton[] FrameSkeletons;

        List<Button> buttons;
        static Button selected;

        float handX;
        float handY;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            InitializeButtons();
            kinectButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(kinectButton_Click);

            this.Loaded += (s, e) => { DiscoverKinectSensor(); };
            this.Unloaded += (s, e) => { this.Kinect = null; };
        }

        //initialize buttons to be checked
        private void InitializeButtons()
        {
            buttons = new List<Button> { button1, button2, quitButton};
        }

        //raise event for Kinect sensor status changed
        private void DiscoverKinectSensor()
        {
            KinectSensor.KinectSensors.StatusChanged += KinectSensors_StatusChanged;
            this.Kinect = KinectSensor.KinectSensors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == KinectStatus.Connected);
        }

        private void KinectSensors_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Status)
            {
                case KinectStatus.Connected:
                    if (this.Kinect == null)
                    {
                        this.Kinect = e.Sensor;
                    }
                    break;
                case KinectStatus.Disconnected:
                    if (this.Kinect == e.Sensor)
                    {
                        this.Kinect = null;
                        this.Kinect = KinectSensor.KinectSensors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == KinectStatus.Connected);
                        if (this.Kinect == null)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Sensor Disconnected. Please reconnect to continue.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        public KinectSensor Kinect
        {
            get { return this._Kinect; }
            set
            {
                if (this._Kinect != value)
                {
                    if (this._Kinect != null)
                    {
                        UninitializeKinectSensor(this._Kinect);
                        this._Kinect = null;
                    }
                    if (value != null && value.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
                    {
                        this._Kinect = value;
                        InitializeKinectSensor(this._Kinect);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void UninitializeKinectSensor(KinectSensor kinectSensor)
        {
            if (kinectSensor != null)
            {
                kinectSensor.Stop();
                kinectSensor.ColorFrameReady -= Kinect_ColorFrameReady;
                kinectSensor.SkeletonFrameReady -= Kinect_SkeletonFrameReady;
            }
        }

        private void InitializeKinectSensor(KinectSensor kinectSensor)
        {
            if (kinectSensor != null)
            {
                ColorImageStream colorStream = kinectSensor.ColorStream;
                colorStream.Enable();
                this._ColorImageBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(colorStream.FrameWidth, colorStream.FrameHeight,
                    96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
                this._ColorImageBitmapRect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, colorStream.FrameWidth, colorStream.FrameHeight);
                this._ColorImageStride = colorStream.FrameWidth * colorStream.FrameBytesPerPixel;
                videoStream.Source = this._ColorImageBitmap;

                kinectSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(new TransformSmoothParameters()
                {
                    Correction = 0.5f,
                    JitterRadius = 0.05f,
                    MaxDeviationRadius = 0.04f,
                    Smoothing = 0.5f
                });

                kinectSensor.SkeletonFrameReady += Kinect_SkeletonFrameReady;
                kinectSensor.ColorFrameReady += Kinect_ColorFrameReady;
                kinectSensor.Start();
                this.FrameSkeletons = new Skeleton[this.Kinect.SkeletonStream.FrameSkeletonArrayLength];

            }
        }

        private void Kinect_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            using (ColorImageFrame frame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
            {
                if (frame != null)
                {
                    byte[] pixelData = new byte[frame.PixelDataLength];
                    frame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);
                    this._ColorImageBitmap.WritePixels(this._ColorImageBitmapRect, pixelData,
                        this._ColorImageStride, 0);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Kinect_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            using (SkeletonFrame frame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            {
                if (frame != null)
                {
                    frame.CopySkeletonDataTo(this.FrameSkeletons);
                    Skeleton skeleton = GetPrimarySkeleton(this.FrameSkeletons);

                    if (skeleton == null)
                    {
                        kinectButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Joint primaryHand = GetPrimaryHand(skeleton);
                        TrackHand(primaryHand);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //track and display hand
        private void TrackHand(Joint hand)
        {
            if (hand.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked)
            {
                kinectButton.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                kinectButton.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

                DepthImagePoint point = this.Kinect.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(hand.Position, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
                handX = (int)((point.X * LayoutRoot.ActualWidth / this.Kinect.DepthStream.FrameWidth) -
                    (kinectButton.ActualWidth / 2.0));
                handY = (int)((point.Y * LayoutRoot.ActualHeight / this.Kinect.DepthStream.FrameHeight) -
                    (kinectButton.ActualHeight / 2.0));
                Canvas.SetLeft(kinectButton, handX);
                Canvas.SetTop(kinectButton, handY);

                if (isHandOver(kinectButton, buttons)) kinectButton.Hovering();
                else kinectButton.Release();
                if (hand.JointType == JointType.HandRight)
                {
                    kinectButton.ImageSource = "/Images/RightHand.png";
                    kinectButton.ActiveImageSource = "/Images/RightHand.png";
                }
                else
                {
                    kinectButton.ImageSource = "/Images/LeftHand.png";
                    kinectButton.ActiveImageSource = "/Images/LeftHand.png";
                }
            }
        }

        //detect if hand is overlapping over any button
        private bool isHandOver(FrameworkElement hand, List<Button> buttonslist)
        {
            var handTopLeft = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(hand), Canvas.GetTop(hand));
            var handX = handTopLeft.X + hand.ActualWidth / 2;
            var handY = handTopLeft.Y + hand.ActualHeight / 2;

            foreach (Button target in buttonslist)
            {
                Point targetTopLeft = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(target), Canvas.GetTop(target));
                if (handX > targetTopLeft.X &&
                    handX < targetTopLeft.X + target.Width &&
                    handY > targetTopLeft.Y &&
                    handY < targetTopLeft.Y + target.Height)
                {
                    selected = target;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        //get the hand closest to the Kinect sensor
        private static Joint GetPrimaryHand(Skeleton skeleton)
        {
            Joint primaryHand = new Joint();
            if (skeleton != null)
            {
                primaryHand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft];
                Joint rightHand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
                if (rightHand.TrackingState != JointTrackingState.NotTracked)
                {
                    if (primaryHand.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked)
                    {
                        primaryHand = rightHand;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (primaryHand.Position.Z > rightHand.Position.Z)
                        {
                            primaryHand = rightHand;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return primaryHand;
        }

        //get the skeleton closest to the Kinect sensor
        private static Skeleton GetPrimarySkeleton(Skeleton[] skeletons)
        {
            Skeleton skeleton = null;
            if (skeletons != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < skeletons.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (skeletons[i].TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                    {
                        if (skeleton == null)
                        {
                            skeleton = skeletons[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (skeleton.Position.Z > skeletons[i].Position.Z)
                            {
                                skeleton = skeletons[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return skeleton;
        }

        void kinectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            selected.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent, selected));
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            message.Content = "Button 1 clicked!";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            message.Content = "Button 2 clicked!";
        }

        private void quitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What data do you want access to in the secondary window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a couple of different ways, and more ways then what is below.

You could pass a reference to the sensor itself to the new window when it is created:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    // init code for window and Kinect

    // show the second window
    SecondWindow mySecondWindow = new SecondWindow(_Kinect);
    mySecondWindow.Show();

    // other stuff...
}

public class SecondWindow : Window
{
    public SecondWindow(KinectSensor sensor)
    {
        // ... stuff

        sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += SkeletonFrameReadyCallback;

        // ... more stuff
    }
}
```

Then subscribe to the `SkeletonFrameReady` callback in your second window.  This might work for your situation if you are interacting with items *in* the seconds window.

Another way would be to create a public callback inside your second window and subscribe it to the `SkeletonFrameReady` event.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    // init code for window and Kinect

    // show the second window
    SecondWindow mySecondWindow = new SecondWindow(_Kinect);
    mySecondWindow.Show();

    _Kinect.SkeletonFrameReady += mySecondWindow.SkeletonFrameReadyCallback;
}
```

I also notice in your code that you are firing events.  If you are wanting to act on events from one window in a different window, you can subscribe to those custom events in the same mentioned above.