# How to pass skeletal data in Kinect Interaction Sample using ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am playing a bit with newest SDK (1.7) and would like to make some changes in one of the examples.

I have a project called [KinectAttractWindow](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/KinectAttractWindow) where I would like to have data from skeletal, depth or color image but I am not able to figure out how to pass these data between view and viewmodel. For example in this [HomeScreenViewModel](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/KinectAttractWindow/blob/master/KinectAttractWindow/KinectAttractWindow/ViewModels/HomeScreenViewModel.cs) I would like to draw a skeleton using this [HomeScreenView](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/KinectAttractWindow/blob/master/KinectAttractWindow/KinectAttractWindow/View/HomeScreenView.xaml). Or how to display depth or color data using the same project architecture?

How to do it in a proper way? Do you hany any advice for me?

I have update my HomeView and ViewModel but I get a NullReferenceException here:

```
'this.RGBImage.DisplayImage.Source =
                BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width,
                colorFrame.Height,
                96,
                96,
                PixelFormats.Bgr32,
                null,
                pixels,
                stride);'
```

Comment: Have you checked what is null? In what file did you put that code?

Comment: This code is from HomeScreenViewModel.cs and it looks like BitmapSource are not providing any data.

Comment: I only briefly glanced so far, but didn't see the DataContect set.  Did I miss it, or is that not that not being set?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey I have added this to my HomeScreenView.cs but the now the problem is how to pass the Kinect sensor object from KinectController.cs to HomeScreenViewModel.cs?

Comment: You can pass it via a constructor, or subscribe to events.  My answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423327/how-can-i-pass-kinect-tracking-into-another-form) might be what you're getting at.  I'm not sure of your application structure, but given the `KinectController` name it implies to me that all Kinect actions should be handled there.  Events can be fired that other ViewModels pick up, or public callback within the ViewModels can subscribe to Kinect events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of allmake sure that your object `RGBImage` and its property `DisplayImage` aren't `null`.I use WriteableBitmap to show my RGB values since it creates one WriteableBitmap-object and rewrites pixels to it so that performance is better. You can find more information on WriteableBitmap [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx).

You can use it like this -

```
WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(colorFrame.Width,
                                                  colorFrame.Height,
                                                  // Standard DPI
                                                  96, 96,
                                                  // Current format for the ColorImageFormat
                                                  PixelFormats.Bgr32,
                                                  // BitmapPalette
                                                  null);
```

Write new pixels to the object by doing this -

```
wBitmap.WritePixels(
                // Represents the size of our image
               new Int32Rect(0, 0, colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height),
                // Our image data
               _pixelData,
                // How much bytes are there in a single row?
               colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel,
                // Offset for the buffer, where does he need to start
               0);
```

Assign it to your image control -

```
this.RGBImage.DisplayImage.Source  = wBitmap;
```

**Skeleton data**

You can do skeletal tracking exactly the same as color data, you `Enable()` the stream, process the data coming in at the `SkeletonFrameReady` and save all the data in properties in your `ViewModel`.
By doing that it gives you the ability to databind to these properties.

Comment: Now I can see data from RGB camera even in VisualStudio or in Blend, when I open [HomeScreenView](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/KinectAttractWindow/blob/master/KinectAttractWindow/KinectAttractWindow/View/HomeScreenView.xaml) but got this error `Kinect is already in use in another process.` so I think that 'KinectSensor' object should be passed in different way or used from [KinectController](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/KinectAttractWindow/blob/master/KinectAttractWindow/KinectAttractWindow/ViewModels/KinectController.cs) but how?