# Kinect skeletal data to transit to another event

Tags: c#, kinect, gesture-recognition

I am currently working on a project in Visual Studio with the Kinect.
I was wondering how to detect skeletal data from a user, play a sound and then transit into another event.

This is the basic SkeletonFrameReady event:

```
  private void kinect_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)  
        {  
            using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame()) // Open the   Skeleton frame  
            {  
                if (skeletonFrame != null && this.skeletonData != null) // check that a   frame is available  
                {   
                    skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(this.skeletonData); // get the   skeletal information in this frame  
                }  
            }  
        }
```

My goal of the application is to use the skeletal data to detect a user, and transit into another xaml file.
Would this be possible? Thank you for you time.

Comment: At first I thought this might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423327/how-can-i-pass-kinect-tracking-into-another-form, but I'm reading it different now.  What event do you want to transit into, or what do you mean by "transit into another xaml file"?  Detecting a player is demonstrated multiple times in the Kinect Toolkit examples, and firing another event works the same as any other case.  If you want to pass the data to another class, the question above answers that.

Comment: As Evil says, can you provide some more information please?

Comment: Basically i want the Kinect to detect a human and use that event to transit to another. I'm very new to the Kinect API. Kind of like the Kinect Toolkit example 'Basic Interactions'. When a human is detected the application transits into the Start page.